# Primefaces Converter not working with dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, converters, selectonemenu

I have a problem with a SelectOneMenu Converter in Primefaces because not display the correct value in a dialog box.
The next code shows what is the problem.

SELECTONEMENU CALL

```
**<p:column headerText="Editar" styleClass="centrarColumna">
                 <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-pencil" update=":edicionSindicatura:contenidoEdicionSindicatura"
                    oncomplete="PF('edicionSindicatura').show()" process="@this">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{listadoSI}" target="#{busquedaMb.sindicatura}" /> 
                    <p:resetInput target=":edicionSindicatura:contenidoEdicionSindicatura" />
                </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>**
```

DIALOG BOX

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    
    >


<h:form id="edicionSindicatura">
        <p:dialog header="Edición de Datos" showEffect="fade" modal="true" responsive="true" widgetVar="edicionSindicatura">
            
        
             <p:outputPanel id="contenidoEdicionSindicatura">
                <p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty busquedaMb.sindicatura}">
               
                                        
               
               <div class="ui-fluid">
        
               <h:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank ui-fluid">
               
               <h:panelGroup>
             
        ......                          
                
        <h:panelGroup>
               
        <p:outputLabel value="#{mens.edicionSindicaturaOnomasticos}"/>
                
        <p:selectOneMenu id="onomastico" value="#{busquedaMb.sindicatura.auxOnomastico}" converter="selectOneMenuConverter" autoWidth="false">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Elegir Onomástico--" itemValue=""/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{onomasticoMb.listaOnomastico}" var="lista" itemLabel="#{lista.descripcion}" itemValue="#{lista}"/>
                                
        </p:selectOneMenu>
                                
        </h:panelGroup>
                                                            
        .....
               
               </h:panelGrid>     
                </div>    
              
            </p:outputPanel>
            </p:outputPanel>
                        
        <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Guardar" icon="pi pi-check" actionListener="#{busquedaMb.guardarSindicatura()}" update="contenidoEdicionSindicatura" process="contenidoEdicionSindicatura @this" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" icon="pi pi-times" onclick="PF('edicionSindicatura').hide()" type="button" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dialog>
      

        
    </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

CONVERTER

```
package es.cortes.archivoCortes.view.converter;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UISelectItem;
import javax.faces.component.UISelectItems;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

/**
 * The Class SelectOneMenuConverter.
 */
@FacesConverter("selectOneMenuConverter")
public class SelectOneMenuConverter implements Converter {
 
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(final FacesContext arg0, final UIComponent arg1, final String objectString) {
        if (objectString == null) {
            return null;
        }
 
        return fromSelect(arg1, objectString);
    }
 
    /**
     * Serialize.
     *
     * @param object
     *            the object
     * @return the string
     */
    private String serialize(final Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return object.getClass() + "@" + object.hashCode();
    }
 
    /**
     * From select.
     *
     * @param currentcomponent
     *            the currentcomponent
     * @param objectString
     *            the object string
     * @return the object
     */
    private Object fromSelect(final UIComponent currentcomponent, final String objectString) {
 
        if (currentcomponent.getClass() == UISelectItem.class) {
            final UISelectItem item = (UISelectItem) currentcomponent;
            final Object value = item.getValue();
            if (objectString.equals(serialize(value))) {
                return value;
            }
        }
 
        if (currentcomponent.getClass() == UISelectItems.class) {
            final UISelectItems items = (UISelectItems) currentcomponent;
            final List<Object> elements = (List<Object>) items.getValue();
            for (final Object element : elements) {
                if (objectString.equals(serialize(element))) {
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }
 
 
        if (!currentcomponent.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            for (final UIComponent component : currentcomponent.getChildren()) {
                final Object result = fromSelect(component, objectString);
                if (result != null) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getAsString(final FacesContext arg0, final UIComponent arg1, final Object object) {
        return serialize(object);
    }
```

When the button is fired the dialog is open but the selectonemenu value isn't show in the correct form. [image: Dialog]This is in the attached file.

Any idea for to solve this question? I have wasted a lot of time trying to find the solution.

Comment: So it works without a dialog?

Comment: Yes, without a dialog is ok. The same code used with a form called with a link works perfect.

Comment: You did not state your version. Can you please try with 12? If it persists, please create a reproducer https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test and report the issue.

Comment: It's 8.0 but I try with 12 and still not working with that version.

Comment: In case someone can help I have found the solution. I have changed the commandButton to a commandLink.